# Input from a JTextField and compare it to the string inputted and then move onto the next JFrame

Tags: java, swing

i've tried searching Stack Overflow and Code Ranch but with no luck with my query. I'll try and make it as simple and straight forward as possible. What i'm trying to do is have a login page that when it's clicked it checks the username against what i've coded and if it's right have it dispose of that JFrame and go onto another JFrame. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
 button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (userTextField.equals(userString)){
                frame.dispose();
                new SecondFrame();
            }

        }
    });
```

Where button is the JButton, userTextField is the JTextField, userString is the String where the username is stored and SecondFrame being the JFrame I want it to move to when the JButton is selected

**EDIT**

```
public SecondFrame() {
    centerPiece.setLayout(new net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout());

    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(500, 525);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

If you want more of it let me know

Comment: `userTextField.getText().equals` instead of `userTextField.equals` and make sure you have `setVisible(true)` in constructor SecondFrame

Comment: Can you post the SecondFrame constructor?

Comment: *"..then move onto the next JFrame"* 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: *"If you want more of it let me know.."* No. Post an MCVE as detailed above, but what is wrong with the current code? Where are you stuck / what is the problem? SO is not a 'finish your code' service..

Comment: Oh, and given it is a log-in, there should be a `JPasswordField` in there somewhere. Though I'm not yet in possession of enough information to tell what (exactly) is wrong with the current approach, I'd recommend making a log-in to be displayed in a `JOptionPane` or a ***modal*** `JDialog`..

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the userTextField's `getText` method as doing `userTextField.equals(userString)` is actually comparing the object `userTextField` and `userString`

Check the javadocs for more info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace this

`if (userTextField.equals(userString))`

with this

`if (userTextField.getText().equals(userString))` ,

because without calling `getText()` method you won't be able to get the string which is written in the `JTextField`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is using MVC Pattern.

1. You should create a `Service` and put all your business logic,
       example, validating username and password in that service. Create
       this method in service in some other file

   ```
   public class UserServiceImpl {

       ....

       public boolean checkUser(String userName, String password) {
           User user = userDaoImpl.getUser(userName);
           if(user == null)
               return false;
           else if (!user.getPassword().equals(password))
               return false;
           else
               return true;
       }

       ....

   }
   ```
2. In your view, i.e., your JFrame, you should first initialize your
       service.You can also create a simple Service object if you're new to
       this concept.

   ```
   public class SwingContainerDemo extends JFrame {
       UserServiceImpl  userService = new UserServiceImpl();

       ....

       button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

           if (userService.checkUser(jUserNameTf.getText(), jPassword.getText())){
               frame.dispose();
               new SecondFrame();
           } else {
               jAlertTF.setText("Invalid Username password combination");
           }
       }

       ....

   });
   ```